# How to change the TextBox background color in Xamarin RemoteView

Tags: android, xamarin, widget

I'm trying to create a widget for Android in my Xamarin.Forms app. The example I'm trying to practice at is here: [AppWidgetListView](https://github.com/Nailik/AppWidgetListView). The trouble is, that I can't find a way to change the color of TextBox background. The `remoteView.setInt(R.id.container, "SetBackgroundColor", backgroundColor);` which is appropriate for Java doesn't work in Xamarin. Moreover, it doesn't even changes the drawable picture.
Please, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it directly in layout `list_row.xml` , just set the background on the root layout

```cs
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" >  //this line
```

---

If you want to change it in code

```cs
//ListProvider.cs
public RemoteViews GetViewAt(int position)
{
     RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews( context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.list_row);

     //add this line
     remoteView.SetInt(Resource.Id.container, "setBackgroundColor", Android.Graphics.Color.Red);

     ...
}
```

[image]